# How to fix "The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/deb stable InRelease' is not signed."?

Tags: apt, 20.04

On Ubuntu 20.04 I am trying to run the following command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

which fails with the following error:

```
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 35.158.216.221 443]
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I already tried to remove stuff like this

```
sudo rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

but this did not help. Anything else I can try to fix this problem?

Comment: Check the file /etc/apt/sources.list and and any files in the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: And what exactly should I look for?

Comment: No it does not. There is no mention of "InRelease" in the file "/etc/apt/sources.list". So I could not remove any offending line in that file.

Comment: Nope. Just searched and grep'ed all files in that folder

Comment: I did uncomment a line "deb https://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/deb stable main" and now it works. Should I replace that line with something else?

Answer (score 2):

Open up the ***Software & Updates*** app

Click on the ***Other Software*** tab

Unselect http://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/debian / or something similar if that is not there

select the close button.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

should now work

Comment: For server, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the line `deb https://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/deb stable main`